# Grails 2.4.3 TagLib autocomplete

Tags: grails, tags

I have an own TagLib and some tags ware using attributes like `controller` and `action`.

For Example:

```
  Closure modalboxLink = { attrs, body ->
    def writer = out
    writer << '<span class="clickable" onclick="'
    writer << remoteFunction(controller: attrs.controller, action: attrs.action, onLoading: 'loadingSpinner()', onComplete: 'removeSpinner()',
            onSuccess: 'viewModal(data);', onFailure: 'errorAlert();', params: attrs.params)
    writer << '">'
    writer << body()
    writer << '</span>'

}
```

When I use this Tag in a GSP i have no autocomplete for the Controller or Action Attribute which would be nice.

How can I get this Autocompletion ?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using intelliJ 15.0

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij you can simply document the tag like this:

```
/**
this tag is super important!
@attr controller controller is hyper important
@attr action action is even more important
@body you can't live without it
*/
Closure modalboxLink = { attrs, body ->
   ...
}
```

I'm not sure about other IDEs though ...

Comment: The Tag is documented like this and i get an autocomplete for the attribute names, but i would like to have an autocomplete  for the value of the controller atribute. The <g:link> tag has that autocompletion, you typ in as the value f.e. `us` and you get a list of Controller starts with `user`. Thats what I want...

Answer (score 0):

This autocompletion is done through intellij plugins.

The [Grails plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18504-grails) that is giving you autocompletion on for the controller and action attributes.

You could fork the [plugin repo](https://github.com/kbialek/idea-grails-plugin) and work off what's there to bring autocompletion to  custom pieces of your application.

Intellij also provides [documentation for building plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/developing-plugins.html), which could help you get started.